# Another record type inside a record type

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, opportunity, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I need to create another record type inside a record type but I don't know if its even possible. If it isn't, what other approach can i try to achieve this? Do i need to create another object? I have so many tabs and creating a new object is my last option. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would be better to step back and rephrase this question in the form of the business requirement you're trying to solve, or the particular technical problem you can't overcome. I don't even know what a "record type inside a record type" even means. It doesn't make sense. Have you read the help page in SFSE that gives suggestions on forming a good questions? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to create a sub-type of your RecordType, you can create a picklist field and select the values available for each RecordType. This is a pretty common pattern.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=editing_picklists_for_record_types_and_business_processes.htm&language=en

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both posts above.  Re-evaluating the business requirement is a good start, but as Kevin mentions, using a picklist within the layout pretty much meets the requirement.

The one short side of this is that you can't have a separate page layout.  Aside from sorting data for reporting, profile permissions, etc., record types are used for dictating what information is displayed on a page layout.  With a picklist field, you can't really get a layout within a layout (unless you go with a dynamic visualforce page).